# SQL: If exists, limit user. If not exists show everything

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exists

I'm trying to found the best way to this requirements:

@fkStaffID INT = Current user.

If @fkStaffID got resource BLABLA only show rows of table X where is StaffID is here. If he DON'T have resource BLABLA, show everything.

SORRY I cannot paste full SQL, for employer's security policy. (I wish I show enough for help, not too much for security...)

What I do:

```
SELECT * FROM X
WHERE ((EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM STAFF WHERE pkStaff=@fkStaffID
AND STAFF.PkStaff IN (SELECT fkStaff FROM SECURITYSUBQUERY WHERE ResourceName='BLABLA')) AND X.fkStaff=@fkStaffID)
OR ((NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STAFF WHERE pkStaff=@fkStaffID
AND STAFF.PkStaff IN (SELECT fkStaff FROM SECURITYSUBQUERY WHERE ResourceName='BLABLA')) )
```

PROBLEM: It's really slow. Can I do a more efficient way? Can I do another way? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why don't you break it down with an `IF-ELSE`?

Comment: I don't see how I can do that, could you show an example?

Comment: What version of SQL? If 2016+, since this sounds like a fairly security-conscious venture, your best bet may be using Row Level Security. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to qrite the query thus:

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE @fkStaffID NOT IN (SELECT fkStaff FROM SecuritySubquery WHERE ResourceName= 'BLABLA')
   OR @fkStaffID = fkStaff;
```

So either the `@fkStaffID` isn't `'BLABLA'` or it matches the record's staff ID.

This `NOT IN` / `OR` still won't be very fast. Anyway, you should have the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON SecuritySubquery (ResourceName, fkStaff);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON x (fkStaff);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
if exists(select 1 from staff where pkstaff=@fkstaffid)
    begin
        select * from X where ResourceName = 'Blabla' and fkStaff = @fkStaffId
    end
else
    begin
        select * from X where ResourceName = 'Blabla'
    end
```

If we have a matching record, then we filter by that `@fkStaffId`, otherwise we select everything.

Comment: Yeah it works... But the only thing I don't like is that I have to copy the code in two places...
In some situation, this code (FROM x in my code) is a huge SELECT: I honnestly cannot copy that code.

If I could just add a WHERE conditions to all existing query, I would be more happier.

Still thank you for a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

The below query will give you only the data for people in X who are in the STAFF table with a corresponding record in SECURITYSUBQUERY table ('BlaBla' records).

First, build test data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#x') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #x

CREATE TABLE #X ( fkStaff int, myStuff varchar(20) )
INSERT INTO #X ( fkStaff, myStuff )
VALUES 
      (1,'not me')
    , (2,'not me')
    , (3,'show me')
    , (4,'not me')
    , (5,'show me too')

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#STAFF') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #STAFF

CREATE TABLE #STAFF ( pkStaff int, name varchar(20) )
INSERT INTO #STAFF ( pkStaff, name )
VALUES 
      (1, 'Joe')
    , (2, 'Jim')
    , (3, 'Bill')
    , (4, 'Ted')
    , (5, 'Rufus')

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#SECURITYSUBQUERY') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #SECURITYSUBQUERY

CREATE TABLE #SECURITYSUBQUERY ( fkStaff int, ResourceName varchar(20) )
INSERT INTO #SECURITYSUBQUERY ( fkStaff, ResourceName )
VALUES 
      ( 1, 'NotAuth' )
    , ( 2, 'NotAuth' )
    , ( 3, 'BlaBla' )
    , ( 3, 'Extra Perm' )
    , ( 4, 'NotAuth' )
    , ( 5, 'BlaBla' )
```

Now for the query.

```
DECLARE @fkStaffID int ; /* Only 3 or 5 will return records. */

SELECT x.* 
FROM #x x 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT s.pkStaff
    FROM #STAFF s
    INNER JOIN #SECURITYSUBQUERY ss ON s.pkStaff = ss.fkStaff
        AND ss.ResourceName = 'BlaBla'
    WHERE s.pkStaff = @fkStaffID
) t ON t.pkStaff = x.fkStaff
WHERE t.pkStaff IS NOT NULL
    AND x.fkStaff = @fkStaffID
```

This will only give results if users Bill or Rufus are logged in (and passed as @fkStaffID).

I don't know how well this will scale, but the optimizer should work faster than EXISTS or NOT IN subqueries. Try it with your data.

Comment: Just ran a quick test with 2.5M rows in #x. Query ran in less than 1 second, so this operation should be pretty quick. And even quicker with good indexes.

Comment: Modified test data to include about 640K positive results in #x for User 3, and query ran in about 5 seconds.